# Need audio player for bash script

Tags: command-line, sound, bash, scripts

I'm working on a small audiovisual project, and I'm writing an auxiliary bash script to control some stuff.

However, I need to play a generated audio file for a few seconds before stopping it, the file also has to start a little into the track, not from the beginning.

The problem is that I can't find a player that works the way I think is the best, it would look something like this:

```
#generate audio file "1.wav"
[audioplayer] start "1.wav" -from 00:20:00 #20 seconds in
sleep(10) #play for 10 seconds
[audioplayer] stop
#do some other stuff
```

I only find terminal audio players that open a seperate GUI or are controlled differently. Is there any way to achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VLC. It has a "console" mode that runs without a gui:

```
start=20                 # 20 seconds in
stop=$(( start + 10 ))   # play for 10 seconds
cvlc --play-and-exit --start-time $start --stop-time $stop $file 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted to achieve. I tried out cvlc earlier but was taken aback by the control-less dummy interface, guess I should've investigated the man pages before asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

an other option is `xdg-open`

use :

```
`xdg-open {file | URL}`
```

examples :

- html

  `xdg-open read.html`
- audio

  `xdg-open music.mp3`

more information [man page xdg-open](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/xdg-open.1.html)

Comment: From the question: "I only find terminal audio players that open a seperate GUI" ... and `xdg-open` will typically open some GUI audio player, this doesn't seem to be what OP wants